# Leaflet, reproduce/call dragging event

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, draggable, drag

I use Angular 6 and Leaflet 1.2 for my project.

I want to reproduce the dragging effect when a user maintain a right or left click on Leaflet Map.
For example, i want to be able to start dragging the map when I constantly pressing the space bar.

I have already test many features like calling the 'mousedown', 'mouseup', 'click', 'drag', 'dragstart' events on Leaflet Map but nothing occur ; the event is calling correctly but the dragging event does not occur.

I'm still blocking on that and the web seem not to search this functionality :o

Thanks for help !
Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add an event listener to detect when the space bar is held down. However you then need to have some way to tell the map which direction to move in. Assuming you want this to be done via the keyboard too, here is some example code to add/remove scrolling via the arrow keys when the space bar is held down.

```
function scrollMap(e) {
  const key = e.key;
  if (key == 'ArrowUp'){
   //scroll map 100px up, or whatever you want
  }
  //repeat for other arrow keys, or inputs of your choice
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  const key = event.code;
  if (key == 'Space'){
    listen();
  }
 });

document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  const key = event.code;
  if (key == 'Space'){
    stopListen();
   }
 });

function listen(){
  document.addEventListener('keypress', scrollMap);      
}

function stopListen(){
   document.removeEventListener('keypress', scrollMap);
}
```

Notes

1) Depending on your page layout, it might be better to attach the events to your map element rather than the document

2) The choice of event.code vs event.key etc will depend on what browsers you are targeting. See [here](https://medium.com/@uistephen/keyboardevent-key-for-cross-browser-key-press-check-61dbad0a067a) for more info

3) Instead of the space bar, you might want to use shift / ctrl / alt instead as these are inbuilt on the keyboard events & so are easier to detect & use cross browser. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_keyboardevent.asp) for more info

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for the response.

In fact, I did not explain the problem correctly :/

I want to keep the dragging effect generated by moving the cursor. I don't want to drag my map by a fixed number of pixel. The defaults keyboard arrow already do it very well.

I just want to call the drag event differently, by pressing space bar for example and drag the map by moving the mouse.

I've just tried another thing :

I have attach event listener on my 'window' object to tracking 'mousemove' event and I drag my map with panBy() method by movementX & movementY of MouseEvent.

Comment: If all you want to do is enable/disable the standard mouse dragging by holding down the spacebar, then simply set yourMap.dragging.enable() or disable() in the document.addEventListener functions above instead of listen() / stopListen()

If your map was created with the dragging:false option set, then the above would only allow the map to be moved by dragging the mouse when the spacebar is held down.

Is that correct - is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yeah i want to do that, without the necessity of clicking (left/right click) on the map to start the dragging.

Comment: If you don't want to use either the keyboard or mouse movements to pan the map, how are you expecting the users to be able to communicate where they want the map to move to?